# python3 - requests - change first line of http request

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

how can i change http request for python3 with requests?
i wanna change first line of request.

My request:

```
GET https://www.example.com/join/login-popup/ HTTP/1.1
```

I wanna this:

```
GET /join/login-popup/ HTTP/1.1
```

Codes are here

```
istekBaba = istekMain.get("https://www.example.com/join/login-popup/", verify=False)
```

Comment: What is istekMain, and what is your problem. I assume you're merely asking how do I make a GET request using python3. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-web-apis-in-python-3 I would take a look at this blog post or add more detail to the question so we can help you more precisely. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: ```ìstekMain = requests.Session()``` i wanna change http's request's first line

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
import requests

url="https://www.example.com/join/login-popup/"
sub_url="https://www.example.com"
istekBaba = requests.get("https://www.example.com/join/login-popup/", verify=False)

my_request_index = url.find(sub_url)
my_request = url[my_request_index+len(sub_url):]

print(istekBaba.url)
print(my_request)

>>https://www.example.com/join/login-popup/
>>/join/login-popup/
```

Comment: thank you man, and i wanna change in request in requests module. error code ```requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'join/login-popup/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://join/login-popup/?```